# How do I make a resultant cell read only?

Tags: javascript

I have a form that allows the user to select a pay frequency (hourly, for example) and displays the annualizing factor (2080, for hourly).  My code allows the user to modify the annualizing factor, but I want it only to display, not be editable.  Can someone help?

Code:

```
function register() {
    document.all.NewFrequency.onchange = OnChange;
}

function Init() {
    var selectionValue = document.all.AnnualizingFactor;
    register();
    if (selectionValue.value == "") {
        OnChange();
    }
}

function OnChange() {
    var selectValue = document.all.NewFrequency;
    var selectionValue = document.all.AnnualizingFactor;
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "Yearly" ) {
        selectionValue.value = "1";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "Weekly") {
        selectionValue.value = "52";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "Unit") {
        selectionValue.value = "2080";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "SemiWeekly") {
        selectionValue.value = "104";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "Semimonthly") {
        selectionValue.value = "24";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "Quarterly") {
        selectionValue.value = "4";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "Monthly") {
        selectionValue.value = "12";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "Hourly") {
        selectionValue.value = "2080";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "Daily") {
        selectionValue.value = "365";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "Biweekly") {
        selectionValue.value = "26";
    }
    if (selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value == "None") {
        selectionValue.value = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the readonly property to true.

Answer (score 0):

As @j08691 said, you have to mark the field readonly:

```
<input type="text" readonly name="AnnualizingFactor" />
```

Or set the readonly property of the input programmatically:

```
function Init() {
    var selectionValue = document.all.AnnualizingFactor;
    selectionValue.readonly = true;
    register();
    if (selectionValue.value == "") {
        OnChange();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Rob.

This is similar to what I tried.  The problem with this is that it seems to make the field read only before it is written to the form, and thus never displays.  I need the process to display on the for, but not into an editable box as it is now.

Not sure if this is possible.  Every thing I've tried seems to prevent the annualizingFactor not to display at all.

Again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why the field isn't displaying, `readonly` should only make the field uneditable. Perhaps I'm confused about your use case, does this fiddle help? http://jsfiddle.net/ubpmfj2k/